# Compare two XML files with same structure and find differences

Tags: php, javascript, xml, perl, diff

I have two XML files. The structure of both XML files is as below:

```
<file1>
       <table>
              <name>...</name>
              <columns>
                       <col>
                             <name>...</name>
                             <type>...</type>
                             <fkey>...</fkey>
                       </col>
                       <col>
                             <name>...</name>
                             <type>...</type>
                             <fkey>...</fley>
                       </col>
               <columns>
       </table>
      <table>
              <name>...</name>
              <columns>
                       <col>
                             <name>...</name>
                             <type>...</type>
                             <fkey>...</fkey>
                       </col>
                       <col>
                             <name>...</name>
                             <type>...</type>
                             <fkey>...</fley>
                       </col>
               <columns>
       </table>
 </file1>
```

Both the XML files will have same tables, but the number of columns can differ. What I am trying to do is compare each column of each table and find the difference(if any) in type and fkey. Also I would like to know which columns are missing from second XML file. And I want to save this info to another file(it can be any format).

I know Perl,PHP and JavaScript but I haven't worked with XML before.

Now what I want to know is where to start and which tools to use? What would be the best way to do above task? Is there any module which provide functions to perform diff between two XML files?

EDIT: I am working on Linux platform(RedHat).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a Perl solution take a look at the related CPAN modules. [`XML::Diff`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aDiff) is the most obvious and seems to do what you need, but there are [several](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=xml+diff&mode=module) to try if that doesn't work for you.

Comment: Just a quick update on the "several" link: https://www.google.nl/search?q=cpan+xml+diff

Answer (score 2):

I once wrote a module that does something similar (not optomized but it did do the trick for me)

http://ekawas.blogspot.ca/2008/11/comparing-xml-documents-semantically.html

```
  use XML::SemanticCompare;
  my $x = XML::SemanticCompare->new;

  # compare 2 different files
  my $isSame = $x->compare($control_xml, $test_xml);
  # are they the same
  print "XML matches!\n"
    if $isSame;
  print "XML files are semantically different!\n"
    unless $isSame;

  # get the diffs
  my $diffs_arrayref = $x->diff($control_xml, $test_xml);
```

Comment: Thanks for the link. Although that's not what I want exactly, but it will help me.